# Narrowing with ClassTag

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I am trying to narrow a generic type. It compiles, but the result is not the intended one (Container(A), Container(B) ..) instead of (Container(A),Container(A)).
What am I doing wrong?

```scala
sealed trait Base
case class A() extends Base 
case class B() extends Base
case class Container[+T](item: Base)


object Test {
  import scala.reflect.ClassTag

  def narrowContainer[T <: Base](list: List[Container[Base]])(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): List[Container[T]] = {
      list.collect{ case t: Container[T] => t }
  }  

  def testNarrowContainer(){
       val li = List(A(),B(),A(),B()).map(Container(_))
       println(narrowContainer[A](li))  
       println(narrowContainer[B](li)) 
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]){
      testNarrowContainer()
  }

}
```

Comment: The correct answer was given on the scala-user mailing list by Lars Hupel. Somebody could post it here.

Answer (score 1):

In this expression `T` gets erased, so all the case actually checks is that `t` is a Container

```
{ case t: Container[T] => t }
```

I think you can add a guard explicitly checking the contents of `t` against `tag` (sorry, don't know the correct syntax for that right now)

Comment: Not really. If there's a `ClassTag[T]` in scope, then the new pattern matcher in 2.10 should automatically check `T` as well.